# HackerRank Array Of N Elements compilation error (Scala)

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I am trying to solve a problem in HackerRank Array Of N Elements with Scala (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/fp-array-of-n-elements/problem) but I am getting compilation error:

```
Solution.scala:12: error: not found: value readInt
    println(f(readInt))
```

The `println(f(readInt))` line is given in the question and it is immutable. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is `f`? And why did you expect `readInt` to exists out of nowhere?

Comment: I didn't understand, it is given in the question and I cannot change or delete  println(f(readInt)) line. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Well, the template is wrong. You can fix it by adding this line before that line `import scala.io.StdIn.readInt`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please complete a [mre]?

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the challenge website. They give this template which you had to specify on the question by the way =) . `readInt` is the function that you have to read from the `scala.io.StdIn.readInt()`. Template:

```
object Solution extends App {

    def f(num:Int) : List[Int] = {
        val list = // Write your code here

        print(list + "\n")
        return list
    }

    println(f(readInt))
```

The solution is here:

```
object Solution extends App {
  import scala.io.StdIn.readInt
  def f(num: Int): List[Int] = {
    val list = List.range(1, num + 1)
    print(list + "\n")
    list
  }

  println(f(readInt))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it but how did you change the println line? Because I am not able to change it.

Comment: I used `import scala.io.StdIn.readInt` on the begin. by the way, there are some thing that the website expects an array, but is suggests to use `List[Int]`. that is strange

Comment: Yes you're right. It solved my problem, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the accepted solution and it wasn't working now. Just don't forget to remove this line

```
print(list + "\n")
```

and it will work.

The full code for the problem is

```
object Solution extends App {
    import scala.io.StdIn.readInt
    def f(num: Int): List[Int] = {
        val list = List.range(0, num)
        list
  }

    println(f(readInt))
}
```